# I am new to backbone.js. I want to create a collection object to retrieve the json object from server

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Here is the data I'm getting from server. How do I store this JSON object in my backbone script and display it in a browser? Please help.

How can i built model or nested collection to retrive this data..
I am getting two kind of response from the server depend on query.
1st response:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [
      {
        "groupname": "Group_all",
        "group": [
          {
            "displayname": "facebook",
            "monitortype": "URL",
            "responsetimereport": "value2",
            "availabilityreport": "value4"
          },
          {
            "displayname": "gmai",
            "monitortype": "URL",
            "responsetimereport": "value5",
            "availabilityreport": "value6"
          },
          {
            "displayname": "zoho",
            "monitortype": "URL",
            "responsetimereport": "value2",
            "availabilityreport": "value1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "monitor": []
  }
]
```

2.Response

```
[
  {
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "monitor": [
      {
        "displayname": "facebook",
        "monitortype": "URL",
        "responsetimereport": "value2",
        "availabilityreport": "value1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

what i have written to achieve this, i am pasting here

```
studentdb.Monitor = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize : function(){
        this.Displayname = this.get('displayname');
        this.Monitortype = this.get('monitortype');
        this.Responsetimereport = this.get('responsetimereport');
        this.Availabilityreport= this.get('availabilityreport');

    }
  });
studentdb.Monitors = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model : studentdb.Monitor });

studentdb.Group1 = Backbone.Model.extend({

     initialize : function(){
            this.Displayname = this.get('displayname');
            this.Monitortype = this.get('monitortype');
            this.Responsetimereport = this.get('responsetimereport');
            this.Availabilityreport= this.get('availabilityreport');

        }

  });
studentdb.Group1s = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model : studentdb.Group1 });

studentdb.Group_outer = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults :{Groupname:""},
    initialize : function(){

      this.outer_group = new studentdb.Group1s(this.get('group'));
      this.Groupname = this.get('groupname');
      this.outer_group.parent = this;


    }
  });
studentdb.Group_outers = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model : studentdb.Group_outer });

 studentdb.Overall = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function(){

      this.group_outer =new studentdb.Group_outers(this.get('groups'));
      this.monitors = new studentdb.Monitors(this.get('monitor'));

    }
  });
 studentdb.Final = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 

     url:'https://data.json',
     model : studentdb.Overall,


  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you must populate a collection with your data fetched from server, and then render your view based on a template.
Instead giving you a complete solution, i think you should first read some tutorials about backbone :

- http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2012/07/22/backbone-js-tutorial-part-1/
- http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection/

Answer (score 0):

could you post your collection code?

I'm afraid your json response probably can't be used directly in a backbone collection.

in that JSON, the array contains two members, the first one contains another array which has only one member (which contains groupName, and group( which really should be called groups))

if it is a 'Groups' collection, you will need to use parse.

docs here: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

it should process your response and return an array of Group model attributes like so:

```
[
      {
        "displayname": "facebook",
        "monitortype": "URL",
        "responsetimereport": "value2",
        "availabilityreport": "value4"
      },
      {
        "displayname": "gmai",
        "monitortype": "URL",
        "responsetimereport": "value5",
        "availabilityreport": "value6"
      },
      {
        "displayname": "zoho",
        "monitortype": "URL",
        "responsetimereport": "value2",
        "availabilityreport": "value1"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: hi Yurai.. can i get your mail id so that i can contact u for more information.. I am not able to post my code here..

Comment: so in the code you posted, what's the relationship between Group1 and Monitor?